# Passing an abstract Graphics object to paintComponent()

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

In Java, when using the paintComponent() method for a JPanel, the parameter that is passed is an object from the abstract class Graphics. Since using an abstract object doesn't make sense, I'm assuming the object that is actually passed is from a concrete subclass of Graphics.

My question is, what is this concrete subclass of Graphics, and where was it generated?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D which is extended from java.awt.Graphics2D
```

each top level Component should have a reference to one, and any child components ask their parent for one until the parent can satisfy the request.